# Exported variable X has or is using name 'OpTypes.or' from external module"/node_modules/sequelize/lib/operators" but cannot be named

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, sequelize.js

```js
import { Op } from 'sequelize';

export const someFunc = (user_id: string) => {
  return {
    where: {
      [Op.or]: {
        private: false,
        [Op.and]: {
          createdBy: user_id,
          private: true
        }
      }
    }
  };
};
```

This was working fine before but after upgrading sequelize to version
`6.12.1` or some other issue the famous error :-

```
ts(4023) Exported variable 'someFunc' has or is using name 'OpTypes.or' from external module "/node_modules/sequelize/lib/operators" but cannot be named.
```

`ts(4023) Exported variable 'someFunc' has or is using name 'OpTypes.and' from external module "/node_modules/sequelize/lib/operators" but cannot be named.` 
started coming up.
I have the following workaround solutions for it :

```
import { Op } from 'sequelize';

export const someFunc= (user_id: string) => {
  return {
    where: {
      [Op.or as symbol]: {
        private: false,
        [Op.and as symbol]: {
          createdBy: user_id,
          private: true
        }
      }
    }
  };
};
```

```
import { Op } from 'sequelize';

export const someFunc= (user_id: string):object => {
  return {
    where: {
      [Op.or]: {
        private: false,
        [Op.and]: {
          createdBy: user_id,
          private: true
        }
      }
    }
  };
};
```

or defining a interface for the object and using it as the return type

```
export interface someFuncOptions {
  where: {
    [Op.or]: {
      private: boolean;
      [Op.and]: {
        createdBy: string;
        private: boolean;
      };
    };
  };
}
```

I tried upgrading sequelize to the latest version as well but it still throws the same error. So I concluded this was a typescript error. My current typescript version for the project is `4.2.3` with sequelize-typescript at version `2.1.0`.

Should i use the above solutions or is there some other solution better than them. Also if I use the above solution will I have to use the solution everywhere I use the symbols of Op from sequelize in my code. Currenlty this is the only place the error is popping up where I have used Op.or or other symbols from my code.

Answer (score 0):

Posting for posterity. I am not using `sequelize-typescript`, but am using `sequelize@6.31.0`. When I upgraded from `sequelize@6.2.5` a few months back I encountered this problem. I also just encountered this problem again this morning.

The solution for me was:

```js
import { Op, WhereOptions } from 'sequelize';

export const someFunc = (user_id: string): { where: WhereOptions } => {
  return {
    where: {
      [Op.or as symbol]: {
        private: false,
        [Op.and as symbol]: {
          createdBy: user_id,
          private: true
        }
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Note the return type.